# C#, Entity Issues in XML New Element node creation

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, entity

While creating new XML Element 'Organization', i faced the entity issues like entity `&#x00E9;`  converted to `&amp;#x00E9;` because of XML escape characters.

Below is the string i have parsed to create new element 'Organization'

`Centre de Recherche sur L' Epidemiologie des D&#x00E9;sastres`

the above string converted as

`Centre de Recherche sur L' Epidemiologie des D&amp;#x00E9;sastres`

in the xml file.

Expected Result in XML File is

`Centre de Recherche sur L' Epidemiologie des D&#x00E9;sastres`

Can anyone help me to get out of this?

**snap**
[image]

**EDITED FROM HERE**

As per richard request, below is the method i followed

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(path);
XmlNode newnode = document.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "affiliation", document.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
XmlElement elem = document.CreateElement("Testing", document.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
elem.InnerText = "Centre de Recherche sur L' Epidemiologie des D&#x00E9;sastres";
newnode.AppendChild(elem);
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using (.NET has, at least, four ways to write XML).

Comment: @Richard, i have added code. what i am doing is open the existing XML File and create the new node affiliation and new element organization

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add an `&`, `<` or `>` to XML text content (including attribute values) they have to be encoded (otherwise they will be confused with the start of an entity, start or an element tag, or end of an element tag respectively).

So what you have looks like correct behaviour. You are adding a literal `&` so it is encoded. When you read the XML with an XML parser the `&amp;` in the XML text will be converted to a `&`.

When you set the `InnerText` you appear to have some text that is already XML encoded – judging by the entity – so maybe you need to decode that text first.

Comment: if i decode that text my entity removed from the string. I want to retain that entity in XML

Comment: @Karthick Sorry, can you rephrase. (And remember if you set the element's text to '"&"' then you'll see `"&amp;"` in the XML text: unless you really want it to be double encoded).